# Apache NiFi identify relationship in Expression Language (routeText)

Tags: apache-nifi

I am learning NiFi and as something to work on, I am splitting the text of Alice in Wonderland and writing each character to different files depending on what character is mentioned on that line.

I have a RouteText Process which splits each line based on if the line contains Alice, Duck, Mouse or the King of Hearts.

The RouteText process is linked to an updateAttribute where I set filename as UUID() and that is linked to a putFile process.

The issue is I want to know which character triggered the RouteText process so I can change the directory that the putFile process writes the file to.

I know I could have a separate process for each character, but if I wanted to check for every character, that would be about 20 processes, which just seems the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, the Expression I needed was ${RouteText.Route}, I was able to assign this to a property called character which I was then able to use to build the directory path with ${character} in the putFile process